# Configuring open LDAP on RHEL 5.5: slappasswd command not found

Tags: ldap, rhel5

I am trying to install open LDAP on RHEL 5.5. I have LDAP 2.3.43 pre installed, I am trying to change password of LDAP root user using command `slappasswd` But when I run this command I get following response/error.

```
slappasswd command not found
```

How do I diagnose problem and configure LDAP on RHEL?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you installed both `openldap-servers` and `openldap-clients`.

Also, try using the absolute path: `/usr/sbin/slappasswd`

Answer (score 0):

You probably are running in a shell with the environment variables setup for a normal user. Since slappasswd is in an sbin instead of a bin folder, you need to be root to run it and your PATH variable should include sbin directories in order to find this. If you just `su`ed to root you might still have your non root PATH variable. Try `su -`, using `sudo`, or using an actual root login (`ssh localhost -l root`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have missing an executable, you can always run `yum whatprovides */slappasswd` it will give you the package that provides this executable and even the full path of that command.

Answer (score 0):

Package containing that on centos 7.2 is `openldap-servers`:

```
# yum whatprovides */slappasswd
[...]
openldap-servers-2.4.40-13.el7.x86_64 : LDAP server
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/slappasswd
```